# How do I make a TestCafe test fail when angularjs throws an error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, monkeypatching, testcafe, angularjs-1.2

When angularjs throws an error, it's caught in a try/catch and then an exception handler logs it as console.error.  As a result, testcafe does not make a test fail whenever this happens, but we would like this to be considered a failing test.  We tried to follow a suggestion in [this thread](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/catch-js-errors-and-console-output/421) and wrote this code:

```
fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://localhost:${port}/`;

const handleErrors = ClientFunction(() => {
    console.error = msg => {throw new Error(msg)};
});


test('Test', async t => {
    await handleErrors();
    //visit page with error, go somewhere else, return to page
    await t
        .expect(Selector('body').innerText).contains('hello world')

});
```

A controller calls `$scope.undefined()` so it will always throw an error in angular code, but the test still passes.  We put `console.error = msg => {throw new Error(msg)};` directly in our index.html, and saw that the error printed out like this: `Uncaught Error: Error: Error: Error: TypeError: $scope.undefined is not a function`.

If we add `window.undefined();` directly into our index.html, TestCafe does consider this an error and fails the test.  The error message looks like this: `Uncaught TypeError: window.undefined is not a function`.

Also, if we put `console.error = msg => {throw new Error(msg)};` in the index.html, the test will fail when there's an angularjs error.  So it seems like the `handleErrors` isn't working as expected or advertised in that thread.

We've done a bunch of tests like this and have now come to the conclusion that angular saves a reference to `console`, so when I re-assign it in this `handleErrors`, it's not affecting the console that angular uses. How can I make errors in angular code fail testcafe tests?

For what it's worth, we're using angular 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

We put this in our test and that caused console errors to fail:

```
fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://localhost:${port}/`
    .beforeEach(async t => await failOnJsErrors());

const failOnJsErrors = ClientFunction(() => {
    angular.element(document.body).injector().invoke(function($log) {
        $log.error = function(message) {
            throw new Error(message)
        };
    });
});
```

There's probably a different solution if you're > angularjs 1.2